# Why does RandomState with a set seed generate new numbers each time?

Tags: python, numpy, random, random-seed

I'm using numpy to set a random state for my `RandomState` object, but finding that when calling the `randn()` method on the object I sometimes get new "random" numbers each time I call `randn()`. By setting the random seed I'd expect to get the same results each time, as the numpy documentation says the following:

> A fixed seed and a fixed series of calls to ‘RandomState’ methods using the same parameters will always produce the same results.

I've noticed that if I initialize `rng` in the same cell as the cell where I create `random_y`, the results remain consistent (same arrays generated each time). However, if I initialize `rng` in a different cell, the values of `random_y` change. For example:

```
##cell 1:
import numpy as np
rng = np.random.RandomState(2)

#cell2:
x = np.linspace(0,10,500) #linspace: generate numbers a to b in steps of c, inclusive of both
random_y = rng.randn(500,6)
random_y
```

this will result in new `random_y` values each time I run the two cells. However, if I were to combine these two cells into one and re-run, `random_y` will remain static. Why is this?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "cell"? Is this an Jupyter notebook or something like that?

Comment: You are probably modifying the random state in between.

Comment: @mkrieger1 yes, apologies for being unclear - a cell in Jupyter notebook.